# Estimating size of server storage

Tags: sql-server, product, estimation

You are about to launch a photo sharing site, what would be the size (as in terms of Terabytes) of your server.

I am looking mainly for how to approach a problem such as this to derive a reasonable estimate. Thanks!

Comment: What is your estimate of the customer base, and what is your estimate of each customer's needs (e.g. number of photos, average byte size of photos)? And server storage is perhaps the easiest thing to grow a bit....

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question...

Photos are quite big compared to the data about them, just estimate the number of photos and multiply it by an estimate of their average size.

Chances are you might need to add a couple of kilobytes per photo for the SQLserver side of it, but this is fairly insignificant. Apart from that you might need fixed overhead of a few mb.